# Want to publish to message queue on Remote machine

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want to publish the message pojo from springboot application running in my local to message queue resides on one of the remote machine, but it is giving Authentication failure exception. I am able to publish the same object to message queue in my local.

I am using Springbatch to read, process and Write to message queue. I have used AmqpItemWriter and trying to publish to Message queue. Its worked well and published the message to message queue in my local. When i changed the property spring.rabbitmq.host from 'localhost' to 'xxx.xx.xx.xxx' remote machine came up with run time exception stating Authentication failed.

Below is my Writer code where I have logic to publish to message queue.

```
@Component
public class Writer extends AmqpItemWriter<CsvWrapperPojo> {

    @Autowired
     @Qualifier("rabbitTemplate")
     private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public Writer(AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        super(rabbitTemplate);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /*@Autowired
    private CSVPostProcess csvPostProcess;*/


    @Override
    public void write(final List<? extends CsvWrapperPojo> items) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(CsvWrapperPojo item : items){



            for(CSVPojo pojo :item.getGeneralPojoList()){

            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve.async_BulkSolve_Msg", "BulkSolve_GeneralrequestQueue", pojo);
            }
            for(CSVPojo pojoSummary : item.getSummaryPojoList()){
                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("spring-boot-rabbitmq-BulkSolve_summary.async_BulkSolve_Msg", "BulkSolve_SummaryrequestQueue", pojoSummary);
            }
        }

    }



}
```

## Below is application.properties

```
server.port=9060
spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=true
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=guest
spring.rabbitmq.password=guest
spring.rabbitmq.host=xxx.xx.xx.xxx(Remote machine IP)
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

I have Rabbitmq installed and same queue is available on Remote machine too. But It seems authentication is not happening here. Below is my exception stack trace. Can any one suggest what need to do to publish message to remote machine.

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar!/:4.0.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

2019-05-16 15:56:41.683 ERROR 696 --- [nio-9060-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step ETL-CSV in job ETL

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:65) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:780) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at com.comcast.FileProcess.Batch.Writer.write(Writer.java:47) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.8.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2):

`guest/guest` it is not allowed remotely by default.

See ["guest" user can only connect from localhost](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users).

> By default, the guest user is prohibited from connecting from remote hosts; it can only connect over a loopback interface (i.e. localhost). This applies to connections regardless of the protocol. Any other users will not (by default) be restricted in this way.

It goes on to explain how to reconfigure the broker if you really want to allow it.

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell. I create new user with proper permissions that worked for me.